# jQuery Selector for all items in body excluding items in specific parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Assume this is the DOM:

```
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <div class="tooltip">
       <div class="tooltip-hd">
         This is a Tooltip for header.
       </div>
       <div class="tooltip-bd">
         Some more info about header
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
       <h2>Subheading</h2>
       <div class="tooltip">
         <div class="tooltip-hd">
           This is a Tooltip for header.
         </div>
         <div class="tooltip-bd">
           Some more info about header
         </div>
       </div>

       <p>Contents inside subheading</p>
    </div>

</body>
```

I want to select all children inside body, excluding the children under the class "tooltip"

The $("body").find("*").not(".tooltip") would select items

Comment: Do you want the `.tooltip` elements themselves?

Comment: This sounds like a bad solution to a problem. Why do you need this?

Comment: Tooltip parent is not required. But would be curious to know if I can skip that too.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? There might be a neater way to achieve it.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to disable click events on all nodes other than the ones under the specific parent.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, but the following would work (though I imagine it doesn't perform very well as it's filtering everything in the body):

```
var items = $('body').find('*').filter(function() {
  return !$(this).is('.tooltip') && !$(this).closest('.tooltip').length;
}).get();
```

This will exclude all elements which have the class `.tooltip`, and all elements which have an ancestor with the class `.tooltip`, so you'd end up with the following:

`h1, div.container, h2, p`